# How get only a few results ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to run a query that displays all the "indexes" but appears some where the `count = 0`. I **don't want to appear** where count = 0. 
I've tried to use `must_not` but not resolved. How do I do that?

My search

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/oknok/base_gerenciada/_search' -d '{
"from": 0, 
"size": 0, 
"query":{
    "bool":{
        "must":[{
            "term":{
                "last":true
             }
         }]
     }
}, 
"facets": {
    "filters": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "spec_veiculo.raw", 
            "all_terms": true,"size" : 999999, 
            "order": "term"
        }
    }
}}'
```

My result (example)

```
{"took":11,"timed_out":false,"_shards":
{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},
 "hits":{"total":8375,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[]},
"facets":{"filters": 
    {"_type":
        "terms",
        "missing":0,
        "total":8375,
        "other":0,
        "terms"[
            {"term":"Abril - Arquitetura & Construção","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Aventuras na História","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Bebe.com.br","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Boa Forma","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Bons Fluidos","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Capricho","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Casa Claudia","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Casa.com.br","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Claudia","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Contigo!","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Elle","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Estilo","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Exame","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Exame PME","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Gestão Escolar","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Guia Quatro Rodas","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Guia do Estudante","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Hotel Pro","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Info","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - Manequim","count":67},
            {"term":"Abril - MdeMulher","count":67}
```

When I use `must_not`

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/oknok/base_gerenciada/_search' -d '{"from": 0, "size": 0, "query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"last":true}}]}, "must_not":[{"count":0}]}, "facets": {"filters": {"terms": {"field": "spec_veiculo.raw", "all_terms": true,"size" : 999999, "order": "term"}}}}'
{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[1MOjVLWpTwmINmoKy8Zh3Q][oknok][0]: SearchParseException[[oknok][0]: query[+last:T],from[0],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"from\": 0, \"size\": 0, \"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"term\":{\"last\":true}}]}, \"must_not\":[{\"count\":0}]}, \"facets\": {\"filters\": {\"terms\": {\"field\": \"spec_veiculo.raw\", \"all_terms\": true,\"size\" : 999999, \"order\": \"term\"}}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_ARRAY \"must_not\"]; }{[1MOjVLWpTwmINmoKy8Zh3Q][oknok][1]: SearchParseException[[oknok][1]: query[+last:T],from[0],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"from\": 0, \"size\": 0, \"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"term\":{\"last\":true}}]}, \"must_not\":[{\"count\":0}]}, \"facets\": {\"filters\": {\"terms\": {\"field\": \"spec_veiculo.raw\", \"all_terms\": true,\"size\" : 999999, \"order\": \"term\"}}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_ARRAY \"must_not\"]; }{[1MOjVLWpTwmINmoKy8Zh3Q][oknok][2]: SearchParseException[[oknok][2]: query[+last:T],from[0],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"from\": 0, \"size\": 0, \"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"term\":{\"last\":true}}]}, \"must_not\":[{\"count\":0}]}, \"facets\": {\"filters\": {\"terms\": {\"field\": \"spec_veiculo.raw\", \"all_terms\": true,\"size\" : 999999, \"order\": \"term\"}}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_ARRAY \"must_not\"]; }{[1MOjVLWpTwmINmoKy8Zh3Q][oknok][3]: SearchParseException[[oknok][3]: query[+last:T],from[0],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"from\": 0, \"size\": 0, \"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"term\":{\"last\":true}}]}, \"must_not\":[{\"count\":0}]}, \"facets\": {\"filters\": {\"terms\": {\"field\": \"spec_veiculo.raw\", \"all_terms\": true,\"size\" : 999999, \"order\": \"term\"}}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_ARRAY \"must_not\"]; }{[1MOjVLWpTwmINmoKy8Zh3Q][oknok][4]: SearchParseException[[oknok][4]: query[+last:T],from[0],size[0]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\"from\": 0, \"size\": 0, \"query\":{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"term\":{\"last\":true}}]}, \"must_not\":[{\"count\":0}]}, \"facets\": {\"filters\": {\"terms\": {\"field\": \"spec_veiculo.raw\", \"all_terms\": true,\"size\" : 999999, \"order\": \"term\"}}}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_ARRAY \"must_not\"]; }]","status":400}
```

And I can't use `Not Filter`

```
{
                            "from": 0,
                            "size": 0,
                            "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "last": true
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "facets": {
                                "filters": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "field": "spec_veiculo.raw",
                                        "all_terms": true,
                                        "size": 999999,
                                        "order": "term"
                                    },
                                    "not": {
                                        "filter" : {
                                            "terms": {
                                                "count": 0
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Are you looking to find all the indexes or all the documents? I don't understand. All the indexes is something like curl http://localhost:9200/_aliases?pretty=1

Comment: Sorry, is all the documents

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Your syntax was wrong.

```
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "last": true
               }
            }
         ],
         "must_not": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "count": 0
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "facets": {
      "filters": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "spec_veiculo.raw",
            "all_terms": true,
            "size": 999999,
            "order": "term"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I keep having count = 0
`(...) {"term":"Ativo","count":0} (...)`

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I did not understand what you meant.

Comment: I don't want to appear as results where the term has `"count": 0`. Even using must_not (running your query), these results appear. I don't know what I do anymore, this really sucks lol

Comment: I can't believe, was this `"all_terms": true`, reference https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-facet.html But the result isn't grouped by name

Answer (score 0):

According to the [reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-facet.html#_all_terms), *all_terms* returns **all items even where count is 0**, only change to *all_terms: false*

```
{
                            "from": 0,
                            "size": 0,
                            "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "last": true
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "facets": {
                                "filters": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "field": "spec_veiculo.raw",
                                        "all_terms": false,
                                        "size": 999999,
                                        "order": "term"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```